# How to retrieve a suffix from url as an action parameter when performing attribute routing in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, attributerouting

Given Attribute Routing in ASP.Net Core (but I guess MVC and WebAPI work the same way), I want to be able to do something like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleController : Controller {
    // GET api/sample/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000/folder/subfolder/file.css
    [HttpGet("{id}")] // this is wrong, how should it be written correctly?
    public string Get(Guid id, string urlSuffix) {
        return null; // return stuff based on the id and the full url
    }
}
```

in the URL taken as example in the comment (`api/sample/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000/folder/subfolder/file.css`) the `SampleController.Get` method should be called with the following parameters:

- id: `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000`
- urlSuffix: `folder/subfolder/file.css` or `/folder/subfolder/file.css` (I don't really care for the leading `/`)

If there are additional query parameters, these should be included in the suffix as well.

I thought about using the raw request URL, but I'd still need a way to specify an action which is executed and what ever I thought of was too late, ASP.Net already figured out that there isn't any URL for the given action.

I would like to use controllers for this, instead of adding some "raw" code into the ASP.Net Core execution pipeline.

**Update:**

This exact example doesn't work for me with asp.net core dotnet core and kestrel service:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}/{urlSuffix}")]
    public object Get(string id, string urlSuffix)
    {
        return new {id, urlSuffix};
    }
}
```

When I call `http://localhost:5000/api/sample/some-id/folder` I get the correct result, but when I call `http://localhost:5000/api/sample/some-id/folder/subfolder/file.extension` I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing: [Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_5)

> Sometimes you have to handle URL requests that contain a variable
>   number of URL segments. When you define a route, you can specify that
>   if a URL has more segments than there are in the pattern, the extra
>   segments are considered to be part of the last segment. To handle
>   additional segments in this manner you mark the last parameter with an
>   asterisk (*). This is referred to as a catch-all parameter. A route
>   with a catch-all parameter will also match URLs that do not contain
>   any values for the last parameter.

Your template and placeholders will change to ...

```
[HttpGet("{id:guid}/{*urlSuffix}")]
```

Given the following URL ...

```
"api/sample/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000/folder/subfolder/file.css"
```

then

- `id = 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000`
- `urlSuffix = "folder/subfolder/file.css"`

Because the `/` is already part of the template, it will be excluded from the `urlSuffix` parameter.

the `*urlSuffix` acts as a catch all for everything after the `{id}/` in the URL. If there are additional query parameters, these will also be included in the `urlSuffix` as well.

You were getting the not found error because your example URL could not find a matching route of `api/sample/{id}`.

I included the `:guid` route constraint based on your original example expecting a `Guid` for `id` parameter.

If the `id` is not going to be a `Guid` always you can remove the constraint and it will work for your updated example.

Comment: Well, that's the problem, it doesn't work for me. I tried to change a lot of things but I couldn't get your example working - see my updated question

Comment: It's the file extension that is causing the issue.

Comment: no it's not, if I skip the file extension I get the same issue it's the `/` that are causing it and for which I don't know how to define the url template so that it will only look at the prefix

Comment: @peter, I've found a solution. updating answer now.